# VS 2022 Debugger seems to evaluate a variable incorrectly

Tags: visual-studio-2022

When I select an expression, `base.ConvertToString(value, row, memberMapData)` that evaluates to a string and use the Quick Watch functionality in VS 2022, it evaluates as a formatted date string of `2024-03-19 08:10:07`.

[image]

However, if I assign this expression to a string variable `v2` and then evaluate it, I see a date string in a different format, `03/19/2024 08:10:07`.

[image]

Since both values were of type string, I expected both values to be the same. Why are they different? I'm using version 17.9.3 of VS 2022.

I am using the CSVHelper library. The class I am in inherit from the following class, in case you are curios:

```
namespace CsvHelper.TypeConversion
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts an <see cref="object"/> to and from a <see cref="string"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public class DefaultTypeConverter : ITypeConverter
```

Comment: It looks like `DefaultTypeConverter.ConvertToString()` is using a different format string for dates.

Comment: If v2 is assigned DefaultTypeConverter.ConvertToString() in the statement "v2 = DefaultTypeConverter.ConvertToString()" , why doesn't v2 contain what the InstantWatch indicated that DefaultTypeConverter.ConvertToString() evaluated to?

Comment: CultureInfo is a thread-specific property.  You don't get to choose which thread evaluates that debug expression.  Could be the current thread if the debug break occurred at a "safe" location, could be the debug thread that the debugger uses to evaluate in unsafe states.  There is no good way to find out which case you get.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable answer to me. If you are inclined to post this reply as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you!